# Remove oil build-up on the touchpad

Tags: cleaning, technology, hardware

Any good ways to remove oil build-up on the touchpad of the laptop?
It's always getting oily ( not sure it's oil or not ). Is there any way to avoid or remove it?

[image]

Comment: As a quick solution, I splashed a pinch of telcom powder on my slippery touchpad and its slipperiness was gone.  Be careful while applying the powder as it can go into under the buttons and can cause damage to it so restrict its application to the touchpad only!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use  windex or any other brand degreaser (not corrosive).
If it proves  too hard to remove, just keep in mind that sometimes due to heavy use the "shine " on the pad is not grease or dirt, but a pad that got its surface worn out over use the same way mouse buttons or keyboard keys get worn out and shiny.

Comment: You might also try water with a drop of mild dish-washing detergent applied with a barely-damp cloth.

Answer (score 5):

I've always used rubbing alcohol, but that's out of laziness. Any alcohol based solvent will begin to wear away at the plastic if you use it too frequently. I clean my laptop every few months with 70% Isopropyl Alcohol, and haven't noticed any wear or functionality issues, but just be cautious of it.

To clean any salt residue, use water, or something water-based (but only a small amount). I just lightly dampen a cloth and wipe. Never pour water directly onto the surface that you want to clean unless you know for sure that it's waterproof.

Answer (score 4):

According to JOFEL (a plastics manufacturer), most laptop trackpads are made from ABS plastic.  This is from their website:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As prevention is far better than cure, by personal experience the best solution to an oily touch-pad (or touch-screen) is to avoid having it in the first place.

```
How?
```

Wash your hands before any touch-pad/touch-screen use, but not with soap, you have to use a mild water-detergent solution -- any detergent will do. The reason for this is that most detergents consist of amphiphilic compounds.

(Amphiphilic (from the Greek αμφί, amphi: both and φιλíα, philia: love, friendship) is a chemical compound possessing both hydrophilic (water-loving) and lipophilic (fat-loving) properties).

Detergent removes any oily traces on your fingers but you have to be a bit cautious when washing your hands because as human skin contains fatty compounds, prolonged exposal to a detergent may wear down your skin. But you can very easily avoid that through the following procedure:

Use ¼ of a spoonful of detergent dissolved in a bowl of lukewarm water and bath your fingers in it for about 30 seconds. Then rinse your hands with plenty of water and wipe them up thoroughly with a towel. That’s it, you are done and good to go.

Using your touch-pad/touch-screen with your hands cleaned this way never allows any oil buildup on these surfaces and this additionally eliminates any danger of causing any damage to your machine while cleaning it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a soft and non-abrasive cloth for cleaning your laptop. Even paper towels and tissues should be avoided as they contain wood fibers. You can use a clean eyeglass cleaning cloth, though. Interestingly, if you
It is suggested to avoid cleaning the laptop with regular or tap water as it may contain minerals and chemicals. Furthermore, do not use soap solutions, window cleaners, or other similar detergents as they can harm the screen. Ammonia and other strong solvents should also be avoided.
If you wish to use liquid cleaners, use Diluted Isopropyl alcohol on a cloth is the best for removing oils and grease.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my P1 Gen2, i7-9850H (a quite expensive laptop), and had a wide range of discoloration on my touchpad. It seems discoloration but actually it's oil, smeared from your fingers which got deep into the plastic. To remove, use **only** a detergent like Palmolive OXY (full is about 3 CA$) + water on a clean cotton cloth.

I used it as above rubbing firmly for a minute or so and afterwards used the same cloth washed completely just with the water. The detergent + water completely removed the oil left on the trackpad. Now my trackpad is as new.

Answer (score 1):

I use cleaning spray for glasses on a paper towel and it works fine. But as stated by Arana, it can just be that you plastic is worn. It then becomes smooth and shiny.